# Custom adapter button onClick() does not change button text?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-arrayadapter

I have a custom array adapter for my Android project. I have added a button to my layout and on click of that button, I would like to have it change the text on the button and also the test TextView, however, with my current code, it does not do that....why is this? Am I missing something? Here is my code:

Adapter:

```
public class JobAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Job> {
    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<Job> jobs;
    private final int layoutResourceId;
    private ExpandableTextView desc = null;
    private Button expand = null;
    private TextView test = null;
    private boolean isExpanded = false;

    public JobAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Job> jobs) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, jobs);
        this.context = context;
        this.jobs = jobs;
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        String pay, hrs;
        final Bundle fragmentParams = new Bundle();

        //LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService((Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE));
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            desc = (ExpandableTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_JobDesc);
            test = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.test);
            expand = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_descExpand);

            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        }

        Job j = jobs.get(position);

        test.setText("testing1");

        //when user clicks the expand/collapse button, expand or collapse the description field
        expand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                expand.setText("test");
                desc.toggle();
                test.setText("testing2");

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    static class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView title;
        TextView payrate;
        TextView dateRange;
        TextView workinghrs;
        TextView location;
        TextView companyname;
        ExpandableTextView desc;
        TextView experience;
        TextView equipment, test;
        Button apply, dismiss, expand;
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/laborswipe_darkgray"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="ABC Company"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|left"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

    <at.blogc.android.views.ExpandableTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_JobDesc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="asdfaa
        \n aaaaaaaaa
        \n aaaaaaa
        \n aaaaaaa
        \n aaaaaaaaaaa
        \n aaaaaaaaa
        \n aaaaaaaaaa
        \n aaaaaaaaa
        \n aaaaaaaa"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        app:animation_duration="1000"/>

    <!-- Optional parameter animation_duration: sets the duration of the expand animation -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_descExpand"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="expand"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas why the onClick() does not change either the textview text or the button text? I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Printing a log message when the button is clicked works, I just can't edit the properties of the controls in the layout at all from the button click.

Thanks!

### EDIT:

Current onCLick code:

```
holder.expand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                holder.expand.setText("testing");

                holder.desc.setMaxLines(15);
                holder.test.setText("testing2");

            }
        });
```

Comment: what is displayed on button "expand" or "text" ?

Comment: By default the button displays "expand" then when it is clicked I want it to display "test".

Comment: comment this // View view = convertView; and run your code again

Answer (score 0):

I think variables **desc,expand, text** should be holder variables not adapter variables. In current situation You are overriding them on every getView method run, so only last row will be clickable ( it will override all previous views in variables ).

Comment: Thanks! I have tried to make them holder variables but I get the "Variable 'holder' is accessed from inner class, must be declared final." If I declare the variables as final in the holder, then I cannot assign values to them...is there a way I can get around this?

Comment: Why You holder is static? Change it to normal class and add public to parameters.

Comment: @user2573690 helped?

Comment: Yeah, that seems to allow me to change the text. One more question, from that same onClick, if I try to setMaxLines() for the textview, that does not work after the public change.

Comment: Public change has no right to be source of this problem. Copy current onclick code.

Comment: Added the onClick() code to the original post. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It seems right code, for sure holder.desc is right view? Maybe problem on findViewById?

Comment: And next thing, are You sure ExpandableTextView has such method, and it working as You aspect?

Comment: I tried to change the ExpandableTextView to a regular TextView and call the setMaxLines() method but it still does not expand the textview, I have about 8 lines of text in it, so it should expand..

Comment: @user2573690 i think this is another problem, this question has little related with current problem with TextView